# display content-type(Strategy) fields value in the form of array in groovy

Tags: arrays, groovy, content-type, crafter-cms

I have a snippets of groovy code (**inside strategy.groovy file**) as shown below in which I want to display the output in the form of desired array.

The content-type **Strategy** (in crafter) has the following fields:

1. Title English (title_en_t)
2. Title French  (title_fr_t)
3. Description English (description_en_t)
4. Description French  (description_fr_t)
5. Players (players_o)

**groovy code (inside strategy.groovy file)**:

```
private createStrategyElement(rootStrategy, ctx) {

    Element strategy = new DefaultElement("strategy")

    strategy.addElement("players_o.first_name_s").text = rootStrategy.players_o.item.component.first_name_s  != null ? rootStrategy.players_o.item.component.first_name_s : "" //Line A
    strategy.addElement("players_o.last_name_s").text = rootStrategy.players_o.item.component.last_name_s  != null ? rootStrategy.players_o.item.component.last_name_s : "" //Line B
    
   return strategy
}
```

**Line A and Line B** display the o/p in the following fashion:

**current o/p:**

```
players_o.first_name_s: "[John, The]"
players_o.last_name_s: "[Cena, Undertaker]"
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

I am wondering what changes I need to do in the **groovy code** above at **Line A and Line B** so that it displays the o/p in this fashion:

**DESIRED O/P:**

```
players: [{
    "item": [
        {
            "first_name_s": "John",
            "last_name_s": "Cena"
        },
        {
            "first_name_s": "The",
            "last_name_s": "Undertaker"
        }
    ]
}]
```

Comment: what do you have in `rootStrategy.players_o.item.component` ?

Comment: Inside that, we have the following fields: **1.** Talent Id (talent_id_s) **2.**  First Name (first_name_s) **3.** Last Name (last_name_s) **4.** Bios English (bios_en_html) **5.** Bios French (bios_fr_html)

Answer (score 1):

don't know what is the crafter-cms. and you have not provided the input for your code.

i found `DefaultElement` and `addElement` in `dom4j` library - so i assume it's the one used in `crafter-cms`

https://dom4j.github.io/javadoc/2.0.1/org/dom4j/tree/DefaultElement.html

you are expecting `json` in output but `dom4j` used to work with xml...

---

however. just a try

```
private createStrategyElement(rootStrategy, ctx) {
  Element strategy = new DefaultElement("strategy")
  def players = strategy.addElement('players')
  for(i in rootStrategy.players_o.item.component){
    def item = players.addElement('item')
    item.addElement('first_name_s').text = i.first_name_s
    item.addElement('last_name_s').text = i.last_name_s
  }
  return strategy
}
```

the following code i used to debug it in standard groovy console:

```
@Grab(group='org.dom4j', module='dom4j', version='2.1.3')
import org.dom4j.tree.DefaultElement
import org.dom4j.Element
import org.dom4j.io.XMLWriter
import org.dom4j.io.OutputFormat

def rootStrategy=[
  players_o:[
    item:[
      component:[
        [
          first_name_s:'John',
          last_name_s: 'Cena',
        ],
        [
          first_name_s:'The',
          last_name_s: 'Undertaker'
        ],
      ]
    ]
  ]
]

private createStrategyElement(rootStrategy, ctx) {
  Element strategy = new DefaultElement("strategy")
  def players = strategy.addElement('players')
  for(i in rootStrategy.players_o.item.component){
    def item = players.addElement('item')
    item.addElement('first_name_s').text = i.first_name_s
    item.addElement('last_name_s').text = i.last_name_s
  }
  return strategy
}

println new StringWriter().with{w-> 
  new XMLWriter(w, OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint()).write( createStrategyElement(rootStrategy,null) )
  w.toString()
}
```